# How do I Write a Java program that identifies whether a number is a perfect square number, if not a perfect number the factors should pop out instead

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

How do I Write a Java program that identifies whether a number is a perfect square number and if its not it will display instead its factors?

I already tried on getting if it is a perfect square or not but I'm stuck with displaying the factors when the number inputted is not a perfect square.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Labor1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");   
        double number = sc.nextDouble(); 

        if (checkPerfectSquare(number))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PERFECT","ANSWER",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);  
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NOT PERFECT","ANSWER",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
    }

    static boolean checkPerfectSquare(double number)   
    {
        for(int i = 1; i * i <= number; i++)   
        {
            if((number % i == 0) && (number / i == i))   
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, remove the JOptionPane statements. Replace with `System.out.println()` to echo the result: `System.out.println(checkPerfectSquare(number) ? "Perfect!" : "Not perfect.");`

Comment: First, some suggestions on improving your code: Enter an `int`, not a `double`.  In `static boolean checkPerfectSquare`, change `number` to `int` type. Change the `for` loop so `i` is initialized with `2` instead of `1`.  Now, when `number % i == 0`, then `i` is a factor. At that  point, you can print it out, or save it in a `Collection`.  P.S. To find all the factors, the loop should proceed up to and including `number / 2`.

Comment: Why are you working with doubles for an integer problem?

Comment: A little more simply put, `if (i*i == number) { return true; }`.

Comment: I fixed the code already but still having problems on how I can display the factors when it's false, I'm still new to this so I haven't really studied that far yet.

Comment: Factorizing is similar, but you will divide `number` by each factor you discover.  One hint is to try multiple times with each factor, because some factors can get multiple hits.

Comment: By the way, although your code uses `Scanner` and `JOptionPane`, the question really is unrelated to either of those.

Comment: Are you familiar with Java [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) API? Are you allowed to use a `List` ?

Comment: It might help if you were to edit the question to include a copy of the assignment.

Comment: The loop in your code is useful for finding factors. (See preceding comments.) But, you don't really need to use a loop to discover if a positive integer is a perfect square or not. A basic, obvious way is `int temp = (int) (Math.sqrt ((double) number); boolean isSquare = temp * temp == number;`